Stored procedure parameter level extended properties in SQL Server Management Studio
In SQL Server Management Studio, is there a way to view/set extended properties on a stored procedure parameter (not on the procedure itself)?
Parameters are nodes in the Object Explorer tree, but there is no properties window on a parameter that I can see. On table columns, there is one.
I know I can view/set/delete them with T-SQL procedures, sp_addextendedproperty and the like, but are they exposed in the GUI? "No" is an acceptable answer.

I don't believe there's a built-in feature, but that doesn't mean you can't build an extension that does.

Does SSMS even support extensions? I know it's a stripped down version of Visual Studio proper, but I don't think it can run VS add-ins. The VSIX install UI doesn't list it as a target.

Yes, it does support them; installation methods are documented.

I think it's much better to write a procedure that lists the parameters together with the properties and just bind it to a shortcut so you can select name of the procedure and get it all listed in the query window. We used this for writing table and column docs and it worked quiet nicely
